# Performing builds and running applications with SDK

Tags: .net, winapi

How can I perform builds on my build server and run applications on my app servers when I install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.

I do not want to install Visual Studio on these machines.

It states "The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. The Windows SDK now requires a compiler and build environment to be installed separately."

Comment: I understand, this is not the answer you are looking for. But *"The Windows SDK now requires a compiler and build environment to be installed separately."* is the answer to your question.